# Переход с Java на С#

Tags: c#, java

Коллеги, подскажите, адекватную литературу, чтобы без воды максимально быстро разобраться в C#,  а ещё лучше книга, где показывают как было в Java и как есть в Шарп (ну это наверно малореально, но хотелось бы)! Работал с Java около года, но меня кинули на большой "дотнетовский" проект WPF, а там и структуры и свойства и ещё что-то, просто шок! С технологиями MS встречался очень редко, в основном MS SQL Server 2000 и Windows.

Comment: Вообще переходы java <-> CLR не должны вызывать проблем. т.к. аналогичные это технологии (но в последнем побольше синтаксического сахара: лямбды, события, var...).

Есть там конечно особенности, например, проблемы с classpath успешно заменяются проблемами с подписями сборок и GAC.

Но будучи неплохим программистом на java, вы быстро станете хорошим программистом на C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй эти книги (сам пару лет назад начинал изучать Шарп по ним, вроде неплохо все раписано):

Нэш Трей - C# 2010. Ускоренный курс для профессионалов

Шилдт Г. -  C# 4.0 полное руководство (очень объемная книжка, но зато довольно подробно описано все от самых основ до редко используемых возможностей языка).

Comment: @MDJHD Спасибо, сейчас попробую ...

Answer (score 0):

> и структуры и свойства и ещё какая-то
> хрень, просто ШОК ! С технологиями MS
> встречался очень редко

Да так то это все связано с ООП, и включается в любой нормальный ЯП, в том числе и Java, а не то что якобы какая то приблуда от Microsoft. Я не знаю как вы прошли мимо структур и свойств, изучая его :) По сути перейти бы было проще и вообще почти безболезненно, а так придется наверстывать упущенное.

Из литературы посоветую "Рихтер - CLR via C#"

Comment: Свойства -- это синтаксический сахар, в Java их нет. Структур в Java тоже нет. Так что неудивительно, что @Oleg_Samitch их "пропустил".
И Рихтера для начала я не советую. Рихтер -- он больше о CLR, а автору скорее нужно в синтаксисе сперва разобраться.